# Will memcache help with expensive MySQL queries? (Drupal site)

Tags: mysql, drupal, memcached

this is a simple question. There are some queries on our site that take too many seconds to complete (like 15 seconds!). For anonymous traffic they get a cached .html file, but for logged in users it's too slow.

The query looks like this:

> `SELECT node.nid, votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.value AS votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average_value, votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.value AS votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count_value, node.type AS node_type, users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS users_uid, node_data_field_species.field_species_nid AS node_data_field_species_field_species_nid, node.title AS node_title, node.changed AS node_changed, node.created AS node_created, node_data_field_picture.field_picture_fid AS node_data_field_picture_field_picture_fid, node_data_field_picture.field_picture_title AS node_data_field_picture_field_picture_title, node_data_field_picture.field_picture_alt AS node_data_field_picture_field_picture_alt, node_data_field_recorded.field_recorded_value AS node_data_field_recorded_field_recorded_value, node_data_field_static_location.field_static_location_value AS node_data_field_static_location_field_static_location_value, field_video_op_videos.video_id AS field_video_op_videos_preview_image_link FROM node node LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average ON node.nid = votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.content_id AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.content_type = 'node' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.value_type = 'percent' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.tag = 'vote' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average.function = 'average' LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count ON node.nid = votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.content_id AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.content_type = 'node' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.value_type = 'percent' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.tag = 'vote' AND votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count.function = 'count' INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid LEFT JOIN content_field_species node_data_field_species ON node.vid = node_data_field_species.vid LEFT JOIN content_type_picture node_data_field_picture ON node.vid = node_data_field_picture.vid LEFT JOIN content_field_recorded node_data_field_recorded ON node.vid = node_data_field_recorded.vid LEFT JOIN content_field_static_location node_data_field_static_location ON node.vid = node_data_field_static_location.vid LEFT JOIN content_type_video node_data_field_video ON node.vid = node_data_field_video.vid LEFT JOIN op_videos field_video_op_videos ON node_data_field_video.field_video_video_id = field_video_op_videos.video_id WHERE (node.type IN ('audio','picture','video')) AND (node.status = '1') ORDER BY votingapi_cache_vote_percent_average_value DESC, votingapi_cache_vote_percent_count_value DESC LIMIT 0, 30`

Will memcache help to serve that page faster? Or, at least, second-time access to it...

Thanks

Comment: My gosh, it looks like you need optimization much more than caching.

Comment: I did, but as some of the tables that needs to be there are large (and I need to sort them, etc) it still takes too much time. In fact, I could paste a query half or less the size, but still slow. That comes from the Drupal Views module, so I didn't code it. Just selecting a few things gives you that...

Answer (score 2):

Expensive queries should be chached one way or another. The query you posted didn't depend on the user being logged in so should be cached.

Have you tried turning on agressive caching in admin, this may help (but could hurt you elsewhere).

If the query is being run from a block make sure block caching is on and appropriate for the query (this would be BLOCK_CACHE_GLOBAL).

Worst case you should look at building your own caching for the pinch points. Only as a last resourt.

*update*: I am guessing that you are using views to generate the page. I have looked [here](http://drupal.org/node/468824) and it looks like the latest views2 and views3 has some caching built in, if you upgrade you may be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't depend if the user is logged in, that's why I know it must be faster (the page). Just can't find a way to do it. I can't turn on agressive cache, as some other modules doesn't support it. 
The query is not on a block, it's on a page. That one: http://ibc.lynxeds.com/content/ranking
You will get the static html generated version probably, as it's a very popular page. But trust me, it always need more than 5 seconds...

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to something on views caching. Prehaps that will help.

Comment: Just saw flashcards answer and your response. Looks like you may have to do your own caching for these (or upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Using memcached to cache the output of this query, or the generated HTML resulting from it, will indeed speed up your page load after the initial result has been cached.

Before doing that though, you should look at the cache settings on the view itself.  In my experience, these settings override the site-wide cache settings in Settings -> Performance.  Assuming you are using Drupal 6 and Views 2, you can set the cache lifetime of a view by editing the view, and then clicking Basic Settings -> Cache.

Comment: It's Drupal 5 - Views 1, so there's no views caching. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

memcached is just a caching mechanism. Your query will still take just as long to perform.

If you want to use it to make things smoother, continually query the database and update the result in memcached in the background and serve up the information from the cache. That way the information is no more that 15 or so seconds old, but is retrieved very quickly.

You might also want to just increase the cache of the MySQL server. memcached is not usually used for caching a single query result...

Comment: Okay. There are more than one query that is that slow. MySQL cache is big already, but as there are too many pages (and pagers) it looks it's not really effective. 
Caching the query on memcached and keep updating it sounds as the solution. I understand the query would take exactly the same time (memcached doesn't make MySQL faster, I know).

Comment: If you also have other queries that could benefit from it, then it might be a good solution.

Comment: mysql query cache invalidates too often (for every table write) to have a real benefit from it, that's where memcache or cached html come to the rescue.